# ¿Cómo conectarse a la base de datos de mi hosting?

Tags: mvc, razor, hosting, sql-server-2012

Para conectarme a mi base datos de sqlServer 2012 de forma local tengo una clase DataAccess con el siguiente método:

```c#
String rutaDB = "Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESSBLA;Initial Catalog=libreria;Integrated Security=True";

public SqlConnection ConnectToDB()
{
   SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(rutaDB);

    try
      {
        cn.Open();
        return cn;
       }
       catch (SqlException e)
       {
          throw new Exception(e.Message);
       }
          
}
```

Y si por ejemplo quiero hacer una consulta llamo al método `ConnectToDB().`

```c#
 public Autor getAutor(int id)
        {
            // aca llamo al metodo de conexion
            cn = datos.ConnectToDB();
            String idAutor = Convert.ToString(id);
            String query = "SELECT * FROM autores WHERE idAutor = " + id;       
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                autor.IdAutor = Convert.ToInt32(dr["idAutor"]);
                autor.Nombre = Convert.ToString(dr["nombre"]);
            }

            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
            return autor;
        }
```

El proveedor de hosting, me provee una conection string por ejemplo:

```
workstation id=miDataBase.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=hola12345_SQLLogin_1;pwd=blablabla;data source=miDataBase.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=miDataBase
```

La pregunta es.. ¿qué tendría que agregar o cambiar en el `web.config` y en mi método `ConnectToDB()` para lograr la conexión a la base de datos del hosting?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que únicamente con cambiar tu variable rutaDb. Debería ser suficiente por que tienes la cadena de conexión en el código.

```
String rutaDB = "Data Source=miDataBase.mssql.somee.com;Initial Catalog=miDataBase;User ID=hola12345_SQLLogin_1;Password=blablabla;";
```

Si lo que quieres es que desde el web.Config obtenerla tendrías que agregar la cadena de la siguiente forma.

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CadenaConexion" connectionString="Data Source=miDataBase.mssql.somee.com;Initial Catalog=miDataBase;User ID=hola12345_SQLLogin_1;Password=blablabla;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Y para obtenerla en tu código así.

```
string rutaDB = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CadenaConexion"].ConnectionString;
```

Igual [aquí](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) tienen varios ejemplos de cadenas de conexión

Comment: gracias @Eduardo Jaramillo Licea, el único cambio que hice fue poner completo el conection string que me provee el hosting.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO! Para lograr la conexión directamente lo hice desde la rutaDB del código, no hizo falta hacer nada en el web config.

```html
String rutaDB = "workstation id=miDataBase.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=hola12345_SQLLogin_1;pwd=blablabla;data source=miDataBase.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=miDataBase";"
```